# Mobile Safari cannot select text or copy to clipboard

Tags: jquery, ios, mobile, safari

Coming across an issue in iOS 8 Safari where I can't select or copy text.  When I hold a finger down on a textarea element with text in it, the option to "Select All" appears for a second, then disappears before I can select it.  Same happens when I can finally get it to select the text, I'm unable to select "Cut" or "Copy" from the menu.

I checked through the code, it's just a simple textarea, focus and blur events aren't fired in jQuery.  Only happens in iOS 8 on the live environment, it doesn't happen on dev which is a direct copy of the live version.  The only difference is www. vs. dev..

Is there anything (jQuery or iOS related) that would cause the options to disappear like that?

Here's a code snippet:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jQuery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("textarea[name=test]").blur(function() {
            alert($(this).val());
        });
    });
</script>

<textarea name="test" rows="3" cols="60"></textarea>
<button type="button">Only here for blur</button>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Same issue here where I can't select, select all, copy, or paste in iOS Safari. The select bubbles are disappearing instantly. I've isolated it to two things:

1. **Adsense code** - Whenever showing non-responsive (mobile) ads on the page it can make selecting text in these boxes nearly impossible.
2. **Updates to HTML** - Whenever an update to the HTML is done, for example with {jQuery.html("")} the cut/copy/paste , select/select all bubbles will disappear.

I can submit an issue to the Adsense team but I still have to test different ways to make HTML updates, perhaps updating a frame instead of the page the element is on.

Comment: Yeah, same thing is still happening here with no solutions yet.  I am able to duplicate the same way, also.  Posted this issue on the AdSense forum around the same time as this with no reply.  Here's the link to the post:  [link]https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/adsense/Ud-HQXZ6iTQ/cSWmqEEEepMJ[/link]

Comment: I've seen some improvement now with copy/paste which leads me to believe they are working on it which is good.